# iPhone Keyboard font

Tags: font

How do I make my Keyboard font on iPhone 6 larger?
I have tried enlarging my fonts on the phone - it only enlarges the typed words I need to have the Keyboard Lager, my fingers are too large so when I type I keep hitting the wrong letters. How can I increase the size of my KEYBOARD?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the size of the keyboard itself, that's fixed.  What you can do is find 3rd-party keyboards on the App Store such as [Thick Buttons](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/thickbuttons/id918142556?mt=8) or [Minuum](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/minuum-little-keyboard-for/id914968934?mt=8).

Answer (score -3):

The keyboard can't be made larger, try finding a third-party keyboard which has support for that.